# IPCC digital references

Tags: climate-change

I'm tidying my citations for my thesis, and I'm facing the task of sorting out the references for the IPCC reports (all of which have **very** long lists of authors).

Does anybody know where there are any existing online .bib files or similar for these references? I'd really prefer to avoid adding them all manually if I can help it. For some reason the IPCC doesn't seem to do this as standard, which seems kind of odd.

Edit. OK I clearly didn't describe this very well. I'm after the references for chapters within the reports (as many as I can) not the references for information cited in the chapters. So AR5 WG1 CH1, Ch2 etc. etc.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the IPCC AR5 reports were written in LaTeX, some in MS Word. You will not be able to get the .bib files for those reports written using MS Word because Word does not use BibTeX.

Working Group I did use LaTeX, and you can get the .bib files for their report, on a chapter by chapter basis, [here](http://www.climatechange2013.org/report/full-report/).

Working Group II apparently used Word, but they have released a set of bibliographies in both .csv and .xml format. I used "apparently" because I am getting errors galore for any page under ipcc-wg2.org. Apparently IPCC Working Group II has not updated their subscription, and some expletive deleted online gambling company has bought rights to that domain.

Comment: I should not have used "apparently" the second time around because it is painfully obviously that some <expletive deleted> online gambling company has acquired the rights to that domain. Except for those who are heavily armored and who access the site using archive.org, I suggest that people no longer go to ipcc-wg2.org.

Answer (score -1):

You can copy-paste your reference from the instructions written on the frontpage of each report. For example, copy-pasted from the 2014 report:

Referencing this report IPCC,  2014:
Climate  Change  2014:  Synthesis  Report. Contribution  of  Working  Groups  I,  II  and  III  to  the  Fifth  Assessment  Report  of  the  Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change [Core Writing Team, R.K. Pachauri and L.A. Meyer (eds.)]. IPCC, Geneva, Switzerland, 151 pp.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It is not anywhere close to an answer to the question. It is a reference to the report rather than to the references used in the report, and it is not even in .bib format.

Comment: @DavidHammen To be fair, to me the question _is_ asking for Bibtex entries for the chapters themselves rather than for the papers the chapters cite, but they can get those from the link you provided.

Comment: @Deditos But this isn't a bibtex entry.

Comment: What I'm looking for is the references for all of the IPCC report chapters themselves in electronic format.