# IPCC AR6 References

Tags: climate-change, climate, reference-request

Does the IPCC publish its references (i.e. the references used in the report, *not* citations for the reports or chapters themselves) beyond what is in the PDFs of the reports themselves?

I'm looking for something like a RIS or BibTeX file (or even a cleanly formatted CSV) of all the references cited, for each of the chapters of AR6 and hopefully AR5. Copying and pasting references out of the Chapter PDFs available on the IPCC's website is a formatting mess not conducive to any sort of analysis on the references.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://zenodo.org/record/6344388

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IPCC digital references](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/20325/ipcc-digital-references)

Answer (score 3):

These are now available for each Working Group report via its respective downloads page:

- https://www.ipcc.ch/report/ar6/wg1/downloads
- https://www.ipcc.ch/report/ar6/wg2/downloads
- https://www.ipcc.ch/report/ar6/wg3/downloads

There are separate BibTeX files for each chapter, for example, the URL for the WG1 Chapter 1 references is,

https://www.ipcc.ch/report/ar6/wg1/downloads/report/IPCC_AR6_WGI_References_Chapter01.bib